# How to take a pre-designed webpage to django and add my own static files

Tags: python, html, django

I've designed a single page,including an 'index.html' and some `css` and 'js' files in separate folders. Then i decided to take my web page to `django` so that i can add database and a little management system to some contents in my web page. But I can't work it out. this is how I tried it so far.

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

**setting.py**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/var/www/html/mysite/templates',)
```

I've put my `index.html` files and it's relatives folders into `templates` folder. But when i run the server it shows my homepage without recognizing my `css` and 'js' files.

I'm wondering what's the right way to do that.
Thanks for your help.

**--Update 1--**

So referring to [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) I've set my static file stuffs like this

I've Created 'static' folder in my project ND Added one more line in 'setting.py'

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then I transferred all my 'css' and 'js' files to that folder.

I added this two lines to my home page to check if it works

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "/img/b-img-4.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Also I tried this command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This is the error line for the new '' tag I added.

```
[24/Dec/2014 19:27:29] "GET /img/b-img-4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2163
```

**--Update 2--**

I found out my mistake. I changed my `<img>` tag like this

```
<img src="{% static "admin/img/b-img-4.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

But problem is that it just recognizes its default static files and folders. I add my own file and folders and ran `python manage.py collectstatic` But It doesn't show the new files I add.

This is my folders srtructure

```
mysite--
    |
    mysite
    |     |
    |     static
    |      |
    |      my css js files
    |
    templates
        |
        index.html
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [This blog](http://blog.xjtian.com/post/52685286308/serving-static-files-in-django-more-complicated) made it all Crystal clear and with these settings I could make it works

**setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static_assets'),
)
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static 'img/author.jpg' %}" alt="My image"/>
```

**Folder Structure**

```
mysite--
    |
    mysite
    |     |
    |     static
    |      |
    |      my css js files
    |
    static_assets
    |      
    templates
        |
        index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly there, but you shouldn't be putting the other resources (JS, CSS, images) into the templates folder. That's only for templates! You need to read the static files docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

This is needed to ensure proper separation of your code (which includes templates - they are a kind of server-side code) and your resources.

(If you come from a PHP background, you might be frustrated by this, because it seems more complicated than PHP where you can just mix them together. However, the way that PHP mixes these things is a really bad idea that leads to [multiple security vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#URL_routing)).

Comment: VoteUp. Thank You good advice. but can you plz check my edit? I can't figure it out I guess

Comment: @AlexJolig for example your static_url is wrong, put something like /static/ there, also do not put a / ahead of static paths

Comment: @DRC I changed static path to this >> `PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static') STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: Where are you putting your own static files? They should be inside 'static' inside your app, (or inside the path defined by PROJECT_PATH) and preferably in a folder within that as the docs suggest. You should then have img tag is src="{% static "yourapp/img/b-img-4.jpg" %}"

Comment: You don't need to worry about collectstatic yet - that is for preparing for deployment. In development, "manage.py runserver" will find the static files if you put them in the right place.

Comment: @AlexJolig can you post the exact folder structure of your static folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your `static` folder is not where it's supposed to be. Try this:

```
mysite
    static
        js
        css
        images
            b-img-4.jpg
```

If your image is placed as shown in the above tree, this should work:

```
<img src="{% static "images/b-img-4.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Comment: I tried that too. But in that way, it doesn't even recognizes its own default static files

Comment: It works if I address one of django default images in `img` folder. but doesn't work if I do it with my new images.

Comment: Can you provide an example (img tag) of a django image (that works) and one of your own images.

Comment: The one in your answer is not working. Cause its in my added folder. but this works fine `<img src="{% static "admin/img/default-bg-reverse.gif" %}" alt="My image"/>` as django has added it in `static` folder